# Replace special characters with other special character in R

Tags: r, string, vector, gsub

I want to remove some special characters to some other special characters. Here are two vectors.

```
a <- c('%', '&')
b <- c('\%', '\&')
```

I want to replace elements of vector `a` to corresponding elements of vector `b` from vector `v1`.

```
v1 <- c('I got 95% in maths & 80% in science',
        'He got 90% in maths & 70% in science')
```

I tried `gsub` but it did't work.
Also I am not able to create vector `b` as it gave following error.

```
Error: '\%' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'\%"
```

Comment: You need `\\%` instead of `\%`

Comment: Need a closing `'` after `science`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mgsub` from `qdap`

```
library(qdap)
mgsub(a, b, v1)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('I got 95% in maths & 80% in science',
        'He got 90% in maths & 70% in science')
b <- c('\\%', '\\&')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to add a backslash to the characters contained in the `a` vector, then you can try in base `R`:

```
gsub(paste0("(",paste(a,collapse="|"),")"),"\\\\\\1",v1)
```

Too bad that only 6(!) consecutive backslashes are needed to perform the task.

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated by the `\` in your object `b` not being escaped.  Try it as below and it will work.  Note that the string itself displays as a single backslash using `cat()` but prints with the two.  To define a `\` in an R character object, you need to escape it.

Note that to do the vectorised replacement of each element in `a` for each in `b`, I used **stringi**, which is well suited to vectorised replacements.

```
a <- c('%', '&')
b <- c('\\%', '\\&')
c <- c("I got 95% in maths & 80% in science", "He got 90% in maths & 70% in science")

(result <- sapply(c, stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed, a, b, vectorize_all = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE))
## [1] "I got 95\\% in maths \\& 80\\% in science"  "He got 90\\% in maths \\& 70\\% in science"

cat(result)
## I got 95\% in maths \& 80\% in science He got 90\% in maths \& 70\% in science
```